# Need to show loading screen while app queries server

Tags: android, multithreading, background, android-asynctask

in this app, the user logs in and their credentials are checked against a server.

The user could be waiting a few seconds, depending on how fast the phone can open a data connection if at all. I need dialog box saying "please wait" or "verifying credentials" or something a long those lines after the user clicks log in.

Desired visual order:   press log in ->  "please wait" dialog is show in this same activity -> when result comes in from server a new activity is loaded (or error is thrown)

Current visual order: press log in -> user waits as if the app is frozen -> new activity is loaded

I'm trying to do this threading thing with AsyncTask but I'm just not getting it right now!

```
class Progressor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Logging In", 
                "Verifying Credentials, Please wait...", true);
    }
```

Then in my oncreate method I had all of the other logic like user clicking the button and stuff, but I've since moved that into the AsyncTask method's doInBackGround function

```
  /* When the Login Button is clicked: */
        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            


            public void onClick(View v) {

                Progressor showMe = new Progressor();
                showMe.onPreExecute();
                showMe.doInBackground(null);
                showMe.onPostExecute();
```

and onPostExecute simply dismisses the dialog box

Why doesn't this work and how should it be re-arranged. What variable should I be passing into the showMe.doInBackGround() function, it is void. In debugging it never goes in here

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how you use an `AsyncTask`, have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Once you have created a new instance of your task, just call `execute()`, not the individual methods:

```
Progressor showMe = new Progressor();
showMe.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't call the `onPreExecute`/`doInBackground` methods of an AsyncTask manually; just call `execute()` on it and it will call all your methods in the proper places from the correct threads. It defeats the entire purpose of an asynchronous task to call all of its methods synchronously from the UI thread (which is what your sample code does).

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar code at the start of my application i load the current settings from the server, it works for me with:

```
public static ProgressDialog verlauf;
public static String vmessage = "";
static Handler handler = new Handler();;

public static void initialize_system(final Context ctx)
    {
        verlauf = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Starte FISforAndroid..", "synchronisiere Einstellungen",true,false);
        new Thread(){
             @Override
            public void run(){
                Looper.prepare();
                GlobalVars.table_def.initialize();
                vmessage = "erstelle Tabellen";
                handler.post(verlauf_message);
                builded = sqldriver.create_tables();
                vmessage = "setze Systemkonstanten";
                handler.post(verlauf_message);
                builded = setsystemvars(ctx);
                vmessage = "synchronisiere Einstellungen";
                handler.post(verlauf_message);
                builded = settings.sync_ini();
                builded = settings.set_ini();
                GlobalVars.system_initialized = builded;
                 switch(GlobalVars.init_flags.FLAG){
                    case 0:

                        break;
                    case GlobalVars.init_flags.UPDATE: 
                        //load the update
                        break;
                 }
                verlauf.dismiss();  
             }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `showMe.execute()`, rather than directly calling `doInBackground` or `onPreExecute` etc.